# How to set up an existing mock using lambda syntax in Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture, automoq

There is a new syntax in [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) that allows me to create a mock from scratch using

```
var newMock = Mock.Of<IInterface>(m => m.GetSomeValue() == value);
```

Sometimes I don't create the mock myself (e.g. when using [AutoData Theories](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/)). Then I have to set up the mock using the older syntax

```
existingMock.Setup(m => m.GetSomeValue()).Returns(value);
```

I don't like this for two reasons

1. It's less readable (imho)
2. It forces me to mix old and new syntax.

I would prefer to set up an existing mock using something like

```
existingMock.SetupUsingNewSyntax(m => m.GetSomeValue() == value);
```

- Is this possible?
- If no, is it on the roadmap?
  I would assume the new syntax to be introduced for existing mocks as well.
- If no, how could I implement this myself?

---

I already know how to use `Mock.Get<>()` and `Mock.Of<>()`, and how the mocks and mock objects are related.

> Moq also is the first and only framework so far to provide Linq to
>   Mocks, so that the same behavior above can be achieved much more
>   succintly

Since there are now two ways to create and setup a new mock, the old way and the new *succint* way, I was hoping it would carry over and also include setting up *existing* mocks.

Comment: You can use [`Mock.Get<T>`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#advanced-features) to get the mocked instance.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. But my question is if I can then configure it using the lambda syntax shown above?

Comment: The `Mock.Of<T>` creates a new mocked instance. It will not work with  `AutoMoqCustomization` because it internally creates a mocked instance for you and the two mocked instances will not be the same.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'm wondering if there is a way to be able to use that nice syntax anyway, with an existing mock. Or maybe some way to write my own `Setup()` method that would accept that kind of argument.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis, perhaps the background to my question is unclear. I have now tried to clarify it.

Comment: Re 'firs and only' ... [Foq](http://foq.codeplex.com) supports a LINQ binding (and lots lots more). I used to use Moq before and now wouldn't go back (admittedly my tests are written in F# but Foq does have first class C# support too)

Comment: @RubenBartelink OMG, that is one of the funniest names for a mocking library that I've ever seen!

Comment: @RubenBartelink, I was not aware that Foq was usable from C# as well. Maybe I'll try that.

Comment: @Cupcake [It was the twitterverse's fault](https://foq.codeplex.com/documentation) but Phil in some presentations is looking forward to seeing what powerful capabilities Foq 2 will bring :) MEMark- have a look at the tests - lots of C# examples too. And you won't be disappointed by Phil's responsiveness. Do [have a look at writing your tests in F#](http://www.slideshare.net/bartelink/testing-cinfdublinaltnet2013) though - it's definitely one thing F# is a lot better than C# at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uploaded the solution code to [my Gist](https://gist.github.com/jwChung/1176df4d2d8be1dc8f46#file-mockextensions-cs-L20-L22). In brief, the gist code has just removed the logic to create a mocked instanc from the original code. To do so, I need to access to the `MockQueryable<T>` class which is internal class, so I used the .NET reflection.

To avoid the reflection code, you can copy the code of `MockQueryable<T>` from Moq source to your test code, as well as some internal types related with `MockQueryable<T>` if needed.

Comment: That works beautifully! Have you considered writing a patch for Moq with this code? If not, would you mind if I do?

Comment: @MEMark I'm welcome you to post the patch. Additionally, I would like to tell one more case why we need this patch.

Comment: `new Mock<IFoo>{ DefaltValue = DefaultValue.Mock }.Of(x => x.Bar() == "Baz" );`

As the code above, we can set up the mock using the `Of` method with Lambda expression whose `DefaultValue` is `DefaultValue.Mock`. As you may know, using the original `Mock.Of<T>` method, we set up only a mock whose `DefaultValue` is `DefaultValue.Empty`.